# Python библиотека для работы с очень большими числам

Tags: python

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не знаю какую библиотеку использовать для очень больших чисел в python (600+ знаков). Хотелось бы чтобы были функции извлечения корня, умножение, сложение и т.д. При этом операции должны быть **точными**.

Comment: Python и так из коробки умеет работать с "неограниченно" большими целыми числами, просто через int. Для дробных (десятичных дробных) чисел можно использовать класс [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). Хотя извлечение корня из любого числа **точным** не может быть (по причине возможной иррациональности результата), может быть достаточно точным для практического применения.

Comment: Вот к примеру "точный" (до 600 знаков) результат извлечения корня из 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSUCK.png Для "настоящего" точного потребуется бесконечное количество времени для вычисления и бесконечное количество памяти для хранения.

Comment: 600 знаков можно сделать так: `math.isqrt(2 * 10 ** (2 * 600))` -> *14142...80162*.